# when the DV ranges from +1 to -1, which regression model?

Tags: regression

I would like to ask which regression model I have to use when the DV ranges from +1 to -1. 
One of IV also ranges from +1 to -1. the other IV ranges from 0 to 1.
These are all continuous variables but some of the control variables are binary. 
I appreciate any comments on this question.

Comment: Let's call your dependent variable $y$. Then $(y + 1)/2 =: p$ is bounded by 0 and 1 and you can use logit or probit link in a generalised linear model. Be sure to use a software implementation that does not insist on values being just 0 or 1. Binary predictors can be left as they arrive. It may or may not be a good idea to leave the other predictors as they arrive. Beta regression might be an alternative. (The usages DV, IV are tribal: for some IV definitely means _instrumental variable_.)

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.